# How do I get the linux kernel to track io stats to a block device I create in a loadable module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, block-device, iostat

I've been looking and looking and everybody explains the /proc/diskstats file, but nobody seems to explain where that data comes from.

I found this comment:

`Just remember that /proc/diskstats is tracking the kernel’s read requests–not yours.`

on this page:

`https://kevinclosson.net/2018/10/09/no-proc-diskstats-does-not-track-your-physical-i-o-requests/`

But basically my problem is that I've got a kernel module that creates a block device, and handles requests via a request handler set via blk_queue_make_request not blk_init_queue, just like dm, I don't want the kernel to queue requests for me.

Everything works fine, but nothing shows up in /proc/diskstats What bit of magic am I missing to get my stats in there so it will show up in iostat? I assumed the kernel would be tallying this information since it's handling the requests to the kernel module, but apparently not. or I'm missing a flag somewhere or something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found it...
it seems the kernel supplies helper functions for you....

you need the request_queue, the bio and the gendisk, call these before and after you process the io...

```
unsigned long start_time;
start_time = jiffies;
generic_start_io_acct(q, bio_op(bio), bio_sectors(bio), &gd->part0);

generic_end_io_acct(q, bio_op(bio), &gd->part0, start_time);
```

and voila, the stats and your block device start showing up in iostat.

Answer (score 1):

The stats file is named **disk**stats, instead of **blkdev**stats or similar. This is a clue. The statistics are output by `diskstats_show()` in `block/genhd.c`, and it uses the `struct gendisk` structures as its information source.

You have created a block device, but for regular disks that is just the first step. After that there is usually `alloc_disk()` to allocate `struct gendisk`s for all minor numbers presented by the device driver, and `add_disk()` after specifying the basic properties of each disk the device driver handles.

But you said you don't want queuing, so you've probably skipped that part to just get a basic block device. Well, you got exactly what you asked for - in fact, the basic block device is *so* lean and mean, it does not even take the time to tally statistics unless *you* make your module do so.

It looks like your driver will get its disks in `/proc/diskstats` only if it participates in the `gendisk`/`genhd` framework. If you don't want to use that, it looks like you'll have to collect your own statistics.

For more details, this might be helpful: https://olegkutkov.me/2020/02/10/linux-block-device-driver/

Comment: sorry, I wasn't trying to skip over information, I was only trying to point out that I call blk_queue_make_request() instead of blk_init_queue() to not have the kernel do queueing. I do call register_blkdev() then get a gendisk from alloc_disk() set all the gendisk params, and finally call add_disk() to create it. The block device functions perfectly I get read and write requests via the callback I passed to blk_queue_make_request(). So I am using the gendisk framework, but at least I have something else to look into now, thanks. I'll check out that blog post as well. Other tidbits welcome :-)